# Create MySQL view of max version without inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-view

I need to create a view of max versions

```
Select * from
(Select * from DSP) A
Right Outer Join
(Select max(SettleDate) as MaxSD, Symbol from DSP group by Symbol) B
On A.SettleDate = B.MaxSD
```

However, I can't use a select statement after the first from in a view. How do I get around this? This must be an easy fix but I can't find anything online.

Comment: Nobody uses RIGHT JOIN. Just sayin'

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query